# Scala how to wait for andThen side effect to complete?

Tags: scala

This code works as expected:

```
val f1 = Future { 
      println("start") 
   }.flatMap { _ =>
      Future { Thread.sleep(100); "done" }
   }.andThen {
      case Success(x) => println(x)
   }
Await.ready(f1, Duration.Inf)
```

Output is:

```
start
done
```

However this code does not:

```
val f2 = Future {
      println("start")
    }.andThen { case Success(x) =>
      Future { Thread.sleep(100); "done" }.foreach(println)
    }
Await.ready(f2, Duration.Inf)
```

The output is

```
start
```

So my question is how should I chain a series on callbacks which only perform side effects if those callbacks also use Futures. To me my second code block seems more "correct" as the side effect is contained within one step of the callback chain

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that a flatMap call can also return a Future with a Unit in it ...

```
  val f2 = Future {
     println("start")
  }.flatMap { x =>
     Future { Thread.sleep(100); "done" }.map(println)
  }
  Await.ready(f2, Duration.Inf)
```